# UPDATE on big table in PostgreSQL randomly takes too long

Tags: postgresql, update, vacuum, aws-aurora

I'm trying to figure out why an `UPDATE` statement takes too long (>30 sec).

This is random, i.e. in most cases it finishes in under 100msec. However, sometimes (randomly) it takes > 30sec to complete.

Some specifics:

- I'm using PostgreSQL 12 (actually, AWS Aurora)
- I'm trying this in a database with no traffic, so it's not being affected by any other queries running in the same time. I'm also monitoring the logs to see if anything else is running, and I don't see anything.
- I've tried `REINDEX` ing, `VACUUM`ing (and `VACUUM ANALYZE`), with no improvement
- I've checked for locks, (`log_lock_waits`) and I don't see anything.
- The query is performed in a loop (from a Python app). It performs ~5000 queries, and at some point some of them, they don't seem to follow a pattern, take a huge time to complete.
- I've tried running them in batches, but again, some batches randomly take too long.
- The size of the table is kinda big, ~10000000 rows and ~25 indexes.

The query:

```
UPDATE "my_table" SET "match_request_id" = 'c607789f-4816-4a38-844b-173fa7bf64ed'::uuid WHERE "my_table"."id" = 129624354;
```

The output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE VERBOSE BUFFERS COSTS)`

```
 Update on public.my_table  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=832) (actual time=34106.965..34106.966 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=431280 read=27724
   I/O Timings: read=32469.021
   ->  Index Scan using my_table_pkey on public.my_table  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=832) (actual time=0.100..0.105 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: (...)
         Index Cond: (my_table.id = 130561719)
         Buffers: shared hit=7
 Planning Time: 23.872 ms
 Execution Time: 34107.047 ms
```

Note that this is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. I'm baffled since while the cost is really low, the actual running time is huge!

I'm trying to understand if this is expected and if I can improve the situation somehow. Any ideas would be welcome, I'm kinda running out!

**EDIT**: Adding some more info requested by comments:

A query plan for a "normal" update

```
 Update on public.my_table  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=837) (actual time=2.037..2.037 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=152 read=1
   I/O Timings: read=1.225
   ->  Index Scan using my_table_pkey on public.my_table  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=837) (actual time=0.024..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: (...)
         Index Cond: (my_table.id = 129624354)
         Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning Time: 1.170 ms
 Execution Time: 2.133 ms
(9 rows)
```

The table has 23 indexes, 6 foreign-key constraints. 3 BRIN, 1 GIN. The rest B-Tree. I'm not sure how to check for `fastupdate` on the GIN index, the output of `\d+ index_name` is

```
 Column | Type | Key? | Definition | Storage  | Stats target
--------+------+------+------------+----------+--------------
 search | text | yes  | search     | extended |
gin, for table "public.my_table"
```

Comment: Are any of your indexes GIN indexes with `fastupdate` turned on?

Comment: Yeah, it hit 431280 buffers to update one row (yikes!) that's probably GIN

Comment: Is the number of buffers affected lower in a fast run? Are there triggers on the table? How many indexes and what kind (@jjanes' guess is probably spot on).

Comment: @jjanes @Laurenz Albe I updated my question with the info you asked for. No triggers. I don't know how to check if `fastupdate` is enabled though.

Comment: It was indeed the GIN index with fastupdate. I switched it off, and saw persistent save times. Slower, but persistent. If someone wants to write an answer I can accept it. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: does this apply to b-tree index as well ?

Comment: @KinShah No, b-tree indexes do not use the fastupdate technique (their update is not that expensive as GIN indexes)

Comment: thanks and very well written blog post

Comment: (For context the noted blog post is https://iamsafts.com/posts/postgres-gin-performance/, a writeup of this whole issue)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GIN indexes have a "fastupdate" mechanism where new data gets written to a specific section in a linear fashion.  Once that exceeds some set size (gin_pending_list_limit, which is set globally but can be overridden per index) the next process which happens along to write to the index gets assigned the task of consolidating those entries into the main part of the index, which can lead to long freezes for that process.  For the length of freezing you are seeing, you must have a pretty high setting for gin_pending_list_limit.

If consistent latency is more important to you than overall insert/update performance, you can disable fastupdate.  Or you could lower the value of gin_pending_list_limit to keep some of the benefit while lowering the freeze-up time.

If you need both consistency and overall efficiency, you could write a manual process/thread which will open its own connection and run `select gin_clean_pending_list(...)` on the index in a loop while the main update operation is ongoing.  That way you get the benefit of the pending list, while the latency of cleaning it up is all loaded onto a background process where it doesn't matter.  (Vacuum and autovacuum will also clean it up, but you can't really get them to run often enough to do a sufficient job of it, because of all the other work they also need to do.  Hence gin_clean_pending_list)

Comment: It's worth considering using GiST index instead of GIN. Both can be used for full-text search. GIN is generally recommended when the data is really updated. GiST is slower for SELECTs but faster for UPDATEs than GIN. It's recommended when the data is updated often, which looks like your case.

Comment: Thanks @AleksanderAlekseev! I'll experiment with this. Yes, the data is indeed updated very frequently so I guess it's worth a shot!